# How to check if email is subscribed in MailChimp?

Tags: python, mailchimp

I've tried [PostMonkey](https://github.com/ericrasmussen/postmonkey/). It does well for subscribing but can't find a function to search my subscribed emails. I'm looking for a way to check my MailChimp list to see if a specific email is found in the list or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listMemberInfo` seems to be made for this. It takes a `list_id` and 1-50 emails at a time, and returns info about the subscribers who are on the list.

MailChimp's API documentation is pretty good, so you can check there for more info. PostMonkey doesn't document all the things that are just pass-throughs to MailChimp's API.